# oncheck checkbox show data in backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I created a template file home.html for my home view with a checkbox in it :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkcompareitem" class="chkcompareitem" />
<input type="button" id="compareitem" class="compareitem" value="Compare items" />
```

Here the view :

```
var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function() {

   },
   events : {
    'click #chkcompareitem' : 'addItemtoCompareLS'
   },
   addItemtoCompareLS : function(e){
      if(e.currentTarget.checked){
           item1.addnewitem(newItem);
           item1.disableCompareBtn();
      }
   },
   render : function(){
     this.$el.html(homeTemplate);
     item1.disableCompareBtn();
   }
});
return HomeView;
```

`addnewitem` method is using for add new item to localStorage.

Here `disableCompareBtn()` :

```
if(compareitems == null || compareitems.length < 2){
  $('#compareitem').prop('disabled', true);
}else{
  $('#compareitem').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

Problem : when I checked on the checkbox, Item is added to localStorage but button is still disable even the length of localStorage > 2.

Comment: There is one answer notification but when I open the inbox, saw nothing here!!

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use this instead of prop.

$('#compareitem').attr("disabled","disabled"); // For adding attribute disabled

and 
 $('#compareitem').removeAttr("disabled"); // For removing attribute disabled